# TimeFormatCyclicRoulette makes kivy app crashed

Tags: android, kivy

At first, my Kivy app runs alright on Android. However, after I add `TimeFormatCyclicRoulette` into my Kv file, the app crashes right after launching.

The below lines are added to kv file:

```
TimeFormatCyclicRoulette:
    cycle: 60
```

I'm new to Kivy app and debugging, thus can't understand the below result generated by ndk-stack:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a5xeltexx/a5xelte:7.0/NRD90M/A510FXXS4CQK1:user/release-keys'
pid: 13562, tid: 13562, name: g.vuche.myclock  >>> org.vuche.myclock <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4
Stack frame #00 pc 000bf63a  /data/app/org.vuche.myclock-1/lib/arm/libpython2.7.so (PyThreadState_New+93)
Stack frame #01 pc 000c9975  /data/app/org.vuche.myclock-1/lib/arm/libpython2.7.so (PyThread_acquire_lock+76)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Since my post was deleted

how to fix this

Edit your: buildozer.prec file and add the packages you need to garden_requirements

Mine looks like this.

garden_requirements = tickline, roulette, roulettescroll

I guess this will also fix your problem.

Comment: To make a nice answer out of this, you should give some explanation, and spend some effort on formatting.